# What happens to activities and fragments when app is in background

Tags: android, android-fragments

I understand the basic Lifecycle of Activity/Fragment but sometimes, when user puts the app in background state for long time I'm not sure what's going to happen when he opens it again. Recently I've encountered a bug: User gets nullpointer exception by calling method of a view saved in class variable (textView = findViewById(...)), inside fragment's OnResume method. The variable is set in OnViewCreated(). Is that possible that over long period of time fragment might lose it's fields due to lack of memory? When onResume() will be called and when onCreate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is in background for a long time its process will be killed by OS, or if the device is running low memory. To test how your app works under these conditions use flag `"Do not keep activities"` in Developer options on your device. In the described case `onCreate` will be called when Activity will come to the foreground.

If the process is not yet killed then `onResume` will be triggered. Normal variables persist, but the problem is that you can never be sure when you're calling `onResume` and when you're calling `onCreate` (since you have no control over when Android just goes and tosses stuff on the stack out the window... anything not currently being used is eligible for destruction).

So my solution is to add a null check with if condition: if the variable is null then initialize and perform actions, if not then just preform actions.